# Factorial ANOVA with a categorical dependent variable

Tags: anova, multinomial-logit

Quick question, hopefully a simple answer. I am running a 2x2x2 study with all three variables being independent and categorical. However, the dependent variable is also categorical, which implies that a factorial ANOVA would be invalid, as that requires a continuous dependent variable. What test should I run instead?

Comment: Maybe R Companion Chapter 8 can help you: https://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_08.html Greetings

Answer (score 3):

The usual starting place with a categorical dependent variable is logistic regression.

Note that ANOVA is the same model as linear regression. But they (as you note) are for continuous dependent variables. There are a huge variety of regression models for other kinds of dependent variables; logistic regression is for dichotomous DVs, multinomial logistic for DVs with more than two unordered categories, ordinal logistic for more than two ordered categories and a lot more.

Comment: Could you expand on this given that someone who doesn't know about logistic regression also often doesn't know about it's relationship to an ANOVA?